# How to subtract two Vector3 ?I want to measure the distance between two Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to measure the distance of two objects(only in the Z-axis) and if the distance of these objects is = 50 then do something...But I can't subtract two Vector3.

something like this:

```
 Vector3 Bullet;
 Vector3 player;
 public Vector3 distance;

 Bullet = new Vector3(0f, 0f, transform.position.z);
 Player = new Vector3(0f, 0f, player.position.z);

 if (distance = Bullet - Player)
 {
 Debug.Log("out of range");
 }
```

Comment: your problem isnt so much that you cant substract two vectors, the problem ist a. that it only gives you another vector and not the distance and b. that you are not doing comparisons correctly (single = is an assignment, == is the comparison). you really should follow some tutorials both on c# and unity before you start on your own project. even if it doesnt appear to you like that now, it will save you a tremendous amount of time in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need and use only Z axis, you don't need extra vectors at all.

You can calculate your distance in one axis just like that:

```
Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z - player.position.z);
```

And also to check for "out of range" you need to use ">=" instead of "==" to avoid bugs when, for example, in one frame your distance could jump from 49.9 to 51.1, and code with "==" will fail in this case.

So the final code should be:

```
public Vector3 distance;

if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.z - player.position.z) >= distance)
{
    Debug.Log("out of range");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Vector3.Distance.

```
 Vector3 bullet = new Vector3(0f, 0f, player.position.z);;
 Vector3 player = new Vector3(0f, 0f, transform.position.z);
 public float distance;


    if (distance >= Vector3.Distance(other.position, transform.position))
     {
      print("out of range: " + dist);
     }
```

source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html

Or you could minus the z values directly. There's no need to use vector functions if you're only calculating the z values.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a subtraction you need, just calculate a distance between 2 vector3

```
const v3Obj1 = { x: 10, y: 10, z: 75 }
const v3Obj2 = { x: -10, y: 15, z: 75 }

function distance(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1) {
  let deltaX = x1 - x0
  let deltaY = y1 - y0
  let deltaZ = z1 - z0
  let distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ)
  return parseFloat(distance)
}

console.log(
  distance(v3Obj1.x, v3Obj1.y, v3Obj1.z, v3Obj2.x, v3Obj2.y, v3Obj2.z)
) // return {Float} 20.615528128088304
```

// code tested